# To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-permissions, subscription

I am trying to upload my apk file to the play store to test the monetization of my app.

What I did:

**Creating a closed testing release**

**Added locations and filled all required dashboard information**

**Add the billing permission to the apk with this command in the android debug app src file `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />`**

**Added this permission in manifest.xml for the app `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version" />`**

I AM WILLING TO PROVIDE ANY SCREENSHOTS YOU MAY NEED TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM

But the play store app still says "To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK" and when I click the button to upload an apk it takes me to my closed testing release. Any reason why this is happening?

[image: Problem image]

Comment: Which library version are you using for billing? Also, check the merged manifest file to see if the permission is included in it or not.

Comment: @Dev4Life what do you mean library version? And where can I check the merged manifest file?

Comment: The current billing library version is `6.1.0`. Have you declared the same dependency version in your app's gradle file? And to check the merged manifest, simply go to the manifest and if you've build the project, then you'll see a `merged` tab at the bottom left of the manifest file window. Click on it and you'll see all the information of manifest file including activities from all libraries as well as permissions.

Comment: @Dev4Life Like this in my build.gradle file?  classpath "com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:6.1.0"

Comment: No, I said in AndroidManifest.xml. Let me post the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the merged Manifest file to check if the permission is exist there?

**You can find the Merged Manifest here:**

[image]

In that `merged manifest` tab, you can see all the libraries and permissions included in the project.

[image]

Comment: I managed to fix the issue - marking your answer correct - had to add a line to manifest.xml for some reason - thanks!

Comment: @CidikoAndorem Ok, great! I'm glad it helped. :)